# Show specific attribute in Woocommerce catalog page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I want to show Labels in my product catalog if a product has a specific attribute.

Attribute Name is "Special" and it contains "Preis-Sieger" und "Topseller".

It works if the product has only one attribute of "Special". But if it has more than one, then it shows nothing.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_specials' );

function show_specials() {
    global $product;

    // Get the product attribute value
    $specials = $product->get_attribute('pa_specials');

    // if product has attribute 'special' value(s)
    if( $specials == "Preissieger" ) {
        echo '<div class="">Preissieger</div>';
    } 

    if( $specials == "Top-Seller" ) {
        echo '<div class="">Top-Seller</div>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: The following solution may be helpful for you: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/315748

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I only want to add specific terms to be listed under the products.

Comment: You can use my code with condition like `if($term->name == '...')` inside the loop `foreach( $attr->get_terms() as $term )`